# How to pass int value from one activity to another and display in TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an integer value in one activity, when I debug I can see there is a value be placed in. The value comes from a counter inside another function within the same class. I am trying to send the variable to another activity and display it in a TextView.

Sending Class:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(TrackingActivity.this, StatActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("yzValue" , getyzVal());
            startActivity(intent);
```

Receiving Class:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    baValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baValue);
    String baVal = intent.getStringExtra("yzValue") ;
    maxX.setText(String.valueOf(baVal));
```

I have tried various solution but it just displays NULL in the TextView.

Comment: You need to use getExtra method for int. `getStringExtra` is for String extras

Comment: you have to write `baValue.setText(String.valueOf(baVal));`

Comment: @TejasPandya I have that added,I was using a different setText before posting. Still getting the same result.

Comment: getyzVal() is an int so putExtra is int and need to get it as int so intent.getIntExtra("key",default_val) or do a cast to explicit type with by get()

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this,

```
   String baVal = intent.getExtras().get("yzValue").toString() ;
```

Comment: What's wrong with this answer

Comment: This works thanks a mill. I don't know why it done a negative vote.

Comment: Then accept my answer.

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes it say, I will accept when it lets me.

Comment: Correct! Your answer no longer has a negative vote..  ;-)  Better 0 than <0.

Comment: very bad way - oString() Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. You should check assignability then cast ...